# Polymer single page app not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created a single page polymer app and when I run `node app.js` the app is not being displayed.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"/>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input-decorator.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
    <link rel="import" href="news-api.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <news-api></news-api>
  </body>
</html>
```

**news-api.html**

```
<dom-module id="news-api">
  <template>
    <span>{{message}}</span>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'news-api',
      properties : {
        message: {
          type: String,
          value: "Hello world!"
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I am just posting my polymer code because the node.js part seems to be working fine. Please pardon me if I have made some dumb mistakes, I am new to polymer and node.js.

Comment: What error are you getting in your console?

Comment: @a1626 There is no errors that is why I have a problem debugging this.

Comment: You have `bower_components` folder right

Comment: @a1626 yes. I have them

Comment: How about `elements` tab in devTool. What so you see there?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127723/discussion-between-a1626-and-nikhil-raghavendra).

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. The problem is with your `self-closing script tag`. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) link to know more about this problem.
Replacing

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"/>
```

with

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
```

should fix your problem